# Error While Inserting a Record and Updating a field using after update trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I wrote a trigger on lead object where it Inserts opportunity record and update the Lookup field on Lead with Opportunity ID.

Here is my code it is inserting Opportuinity Record but it is not updating the field. And I want to use after Update only !!

```
public class TriggerHelper {

    public static boolean isExecuting = false;


    public static void updateValues(){
  List<Opportunity> opp = new List<Opportunity>();
        if( TriggerHelper.isExecuting ){
            // if was executed durinListg the same context 
            // avoid recursion
            return;
        }

        TriggerHelper.isExecuting = true; 

        //list of new instance of object to update. 
        Lead[] lds = new Lead[]{};
      System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
        for (Lead a : (List<Lead>)Trigger.new) {  
        if(a.LastName == 'test'){

    Opportunity op = new Opportunity();
    op.Name = a.LastName;
    op.CloseDate= System.today()+20;
    op.StageName = 'Prospecting';
    opp.add(op);

    System.debug('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'+op);

            //here the magic by creating a new instance using the same id
            Lead aux  = new Lead(Id = a.Id);       
            aux.Opportunity__c =  opp[0].Id;


        System.debug('%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%');
        } 

    }   
        //then update the new instance list. 
        Insert opp;
        Update lds;

    }

}
```

Trigger :

```
trigger mytrig on Lead (after Update){
TriggerHelper.updateValues();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger and pass `trigger.New`

```
trigger mytrig on Lead (after Update){
   TriggerHelper.updateValues(Trigger.New);
}
```

Helper class

```
public class TriggerHelper {
    public static boolean isExecuting = false;

    public static void updateValues(List<Opportunity> lstLead){
    List<Opportunity> opp = new List<Opportunity>();
        if( TriggerHelper.isExecuting ){
            // if was executed durinListg the same context 
            // avoid recursion
            return;
        }

        TriggerHelper.isExecuting = true; 

        map<Id, Opportunity> mapLeadIdToOpportunity = new map<Id, Opportunity>();

        //iterate over list and create new opp instance and add into map
        for(Lead objLead: lstLead){
            Opportunity op = new Opportunity();
            op.Name = a.LastName;
            op.CloseDate= System.today()+20;
            op.StageName = 'Prospecting';
            mapLeadIdToOpportunity.put(objLead.Id, op);
        }
        //now insert all the opportunity.. now in opp having ids
        insert mapLeadIdToOpportunity.Values();
        List<Lead> lstLeadToUpdate = new List<Lead>();
        // now iterate over keyset and get the opp id and assign to lead
        for(Id leadId: mapLeadIdToOpportunity.keyset())
        {
            lstLeadToUpdate.add(new Lead(Id = leadId, Opportunity__c = mapLeadIdToOpportunity.get(leadId).Id));
        }
        // update lead
        update lstLeadToUpdate;
    }
}
```

---

It would be a good solution if we use in before update

You don't have to perform update DML

you just need to change below code

```
for(Id leadId: mapLeadIdToOpportunity.keyset())
{
     lstLeadToUpdate.add(new Lead(Id = leadId, Opportunity__c = mapLeadIdToOpportunity.get(leadId).Id));
 }
```

instead

```
for(Lead objLead: lstLead)
{
    objLead.Opportunity__c  = mapLeadIdToOpportunity.get(leadId).Id;
 }
```

Comment: Some basic explanation of this answer is this. The `Opportunity` you're creating won't have an Id until **after** it is inserted. That means that you need to separate the process of creating the `Opportunity` from updating your `Lead`. To keep track of which `Lead` created which `Opportunity`, you store the Opp in a map, keyed on the Lead's Id. After inserting, the reference to the `Opportunities` in the map will have their Id field available (and not null).

Comment: @DerekF when you commenting actually I was updating my ans with my comments check ..

Comment: Additionally, I believe this is a case to use a `Before Update` trigger, rather than an `After Update` trigger, as you are updating the same `Lead` records that are in `Trigger.New`

Comment: @DerekF Yeah I am total agree but if you check question OP wants in `After update` only.

Comment: Just a personal preference of mine to have an explanation outside of the code. On your second point, yes, the OP wanted an `After Update` trigger, but sometimes what we want isn't exactly what we need (or what should be used). Without additional context, it's very hard to justify not noting that this should probably be a `Before Update` trigger.

Comment: @DerekF As I am new to salesforce I really don't have much idea about  trigger but I will keep in mind your points. thank you